# Что означает &> в скрипте bash?

Tags: bash

Я наткнулся на чужой bash скрипт в котором была команда

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0 &> "/dev/null"`

и я хочу знать что означает `&>`

Comment: В твоём случае добавить stderr в вывод. И тут-же отправить в /dev/null . Смысл в том что `cmd > outbuffer` выводит только stdout, а `cmd &> outbuffer` отправляет stdout и stderr

Comment: https://catonmat.net/ftp/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.txt

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1354345/178576)