# Почему даже при исполнении скрипта bash с &> /dev/null все равно выводит в терминал

Tags: bash

Я использую следующий скрипт

```
#!/bin/sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0 &> /dev/null
```

Даю ему права `chmod +x temp.sh`
Затем выполняю его `sudo ./temp.sh` вывод в терминале

```
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0
```

Вопрос почему вообще идёт вывод если я использую `&> /dev/null` и как мне полность убрать вывод?

Comment: Откуда там bin/sh в выводе? Что вы вообще запускаете?

Comment: @AlexeyTen извиняюсь исправил

Comment: Так а почему bin/sh, а не bin/bash? `&>` это башизм

Comment: `&>` — это башизм... скорей всего `/bin/sh` ссылается у тебя на другой шелл, например dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо исправьте шебанг на bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0 &> /dev/null
```

Либо не используйте `&>`, а напишите стандартное перенаправление

```sh
#!/bin/sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0 > /dev/null 2>&1
```